# How to have sprite kit automatically resize depending on dimension of phone

Tags: sprite-kit

At the moment, to handle the different screen sizes of the iphone 4 and 5 i use the following:

```
if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width == 568)
{
   -----
} else {
   -----
}
```

But with the edition of the 6 and 6 plus, this just seems like to much code to do for everything that requires a position on the screen. Is there an easier way to do this, where it automatically resizes for you?

Comment: Have you tried Scale to fill?

Comment: What are you trying to resize? If you're resizing images, use the asset catalogs that Xcode provides you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an application using iPhone 6 dimensions in SpriteKit SKS files. When switching scenes I used the following code, the game scaled automatically when testing on different devices.

```
let yourScene = yourSceneFile(fileNamed: "YourScene")
gameplay!.scaleMode = .AspectFill
self.view?.presentScene(yourScene, transition)
```